# How do I avoid listing all the table columns in a PostgreSQL returns statement?

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a PostgreSQL function similar to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.MyTestFunction(
    _ID INT
)
RETURNS dbo.MyTable AS
$$
    SELECT  *,
            (SELECT Name FROM dbo.MySecondTable WHERE RecordID = PersonID)
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    WHERE PersonID = _ID
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

I would really like to NOT have to replace the RETURNS dbo.MyTable AS with something like:

```
RETURNS TABLE(
    col1 INT,
    col2 TEXT,
    col3 BOOLEAN,
    col4 TEXT
) AS
```

and list out all the columns of MyTable and Name of MySecondTable. Is this something that can be done? Thanks.

--EDIT-- 
To clarify I have to return ALL columns in MyTable and 1 column from MySecondTable. If MyTable has >15 columns, I don't want to have to list out all the columns in a RETURNS TABLE (col1.. coln).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just list the columns that you want returned in the `SELECT` portion of your SQL statement:

```
SELECT  t1.column1, t1.column2,
        (SELECT Name FROM dbo.MySecondTable WHERE RecordID = PersonID)
FROM dbo.MyTable t1
WHERE PersonID = _ID
```

Now you'll just get `column1`, `column3`, and `name` returned

---

Furthermore, you'll probably find better performance using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in your `FROM` portion of the SQL statement as opposed to the correlated subquery you have now:

```
SELECT  t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.Name
FROM dbo.MyTable t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MySecondTable t2 ON
        t2.RecordID = t1.PersonID
WHERE PersonID = _ID
```

Took a bit of a guess on where `RecordID` and `PersonID` were coming from, but that's the general idea.

Comment: First, thanks for the quick reply and the bonus suggestion on performance!

The issue is that I'm trying to AVOID listing out all the columns I'd like to return. Mainly due in part because I need to return ALL (SELECT *) from MyTable, and 1 additional column from MySecondTable.

MyTable has 15 or so columns that I don't want to have to list out in a: RETURNS TABLE( col1, ..., coln). I'm looking for a way to avoid that

Comment: @Anduril28: the simple answer is: there is no shortcut. Plus I fail so see what the problem is. You write this once, it's not that would do that ever minute or so. Writing the question and this comment probably took you longer than just writing those 16 columns...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I wouldn't know that without asking. The problem is, I'm converting a database with 9000 different functions. A good 500+ have this sort of scenario. So, not too unreasonable to hope for an easier way to do this I would say.